# How to do lemmatization arabic text

Tags: java, python, arabic, lemmatization

How do i perform a lemmatization on arabic raw text?

I'm familiar with the stanford nlp jars. (http://nlp.stanford.edu/projects/arabic.shtml)

But unfortunately this does not offer a proper lemmatization.

Answer (score 0):

I figured that out, in the Stanford coreNLP lib there is a lemmatization.